# Cross Domain SSO with DotenetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have integrated `DotenetOpenAuth` to login using google account.
Its working perfect.
Can i achieve this with it ?
Once user logged in `site1.com` if user browse to `site2.com` the user get automatically logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth includes a `Samples` directory. There are `OpenIdWebRingSsoProvider` and `OpenIdWebRingSsoRelyingParty` projects which, I believe, do exactly what you want to achieve. Though, you have to implement your own central SSO provider.

Comment: can you please elaborate `central SSO provider`

Comment: Have you tried looking into example projects? Well, my point is that for site2 to **know for sure** that a user is logged in to site1, I believe you have to implement some authentication providing party. I think you cannot just ask Google from site2 - "is this user logged in to site1?". That would be insecure. So when a user visits site2, it should redirect a user to site1's SSO provider which is similar to the one in the example project. Then SSO provider would check if the user is indeed who he claims to be and if he is logged in. On success, it will redirect the user back to site1.

Comment: does `DotenetOpenAuth` provides both `authentication` and `authorization` ?

Comment: If the answer helped you, mark it as accepted. Otherwise, consider asking more questions in the comments.